# Pnpm cannot import @testing-library/jest-dom/matchers

Tags: react-testing-library, pnpm

I'm migrating from npm to pnpm. I have problem with unit tests.
This import gives me error:

```
import matchers from '@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers';
```

> Could not find a declaration file for module '@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers'. 'C:/Users/Mateusz-Astrafox/source/repos/AMODIT/AMODWebAppFrontend/node_modules/.pnpm/@testing-library+jest-dom@5.16.5/node_modules/@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm i --save-dev @types/testing-library__jest-dom` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers';

I tried installing @types/testing-library__jest-dom, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the library you're trying to use is different from the one you've installed.  Try `pnpm install --save-dev @testing-library/jest-dom` (not `__jest-dom`)